# Discord.py команда антиспам

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Хочу на своем сервере сделать команду которая запрещает писать гифки после ввода команды(запрещает писать 10 гифок потом команда отклоняется автоматически),но не могу понять логику, и ошибка вылезает: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Message' and 'int'
я понял суть ошибки, но как правильно ее переписать

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    # Чтобы бот не был шизиком
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    for all_gif in vse:
        if message.content.startswith(#Command):
            pass
        elif all_gif in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            global ora
            ora = await message.channel.send(#Reaction on gif)
        elif ora > 10:
            break
        else: pass
```

Answer (score 1):

`ora` - Переменная, которая является объектом класса Message. Переписать можно так:

```
global count
count = 0
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    # Чтобы бот не был шизиком
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    for all_gif in vse:

        count =+ 1
 
        if message.content.startswith('Test'): #Command
            pass

        if count => 10:
            count = 0
            break
        elif all_gif in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            ora = await message.channel.send('Test') #Reaction on gif
```

Comment: все также, цикл не прекращается, но ошибки нет

Comment: не могли бы вы проверить свой код на достоверность, довольно много ошибок после ваших исправлений:
count += 1 / count =+ 1
count => 10 / count >= 10
почему в коде 2 раза повторяется  count = 0

Comment: Также хочу отметить что бот даже когда команда еще не введена все равно удаляет гифки